# Parse String in PHP

Tags: php

```
{"status":"ok","params":{"stream_token":"token=lTQ4sJx9vK7pR7kgeYVDgQ&e=1448284525&u=37997"}}
```

I would like to parse this string and need

> token=lTQ4sJx9vK7pR7kgeYVDgQ&e=1448284525&u=37997

Hows that possible in PHP?

```
echo json_decode('{"status":"ok","params":{"stream_token":"token=U8h5Ma12SrlizPoFm-Nc5w&e=1448285819&u=37997"}}');
```

throuse the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string

Comment: Don't try eching an object; just retrieve the value you want from the object: `$value = json_decode('{"status":"ok","params":{"stream_token":"token=U8h5Ma12SrlizPoFm-Nc5w&e=1448285819&u=37997"}}');
echo $value->stream_token;`

Comment: yes, its for just help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the extra parameter to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to retrieve the result as an associative array:

```
$data = json_decode('{"status":"ok","params":{"stream_token":"token=U8h5Ma12SrlizPoFm-Nc5w&e=1448285819&u=37997"}}', TRUE);
$url= $data['params']['stream_token'];    
var_dump($url); // token=U8h5Ma12SrlizPoFm-Nc5w&e=1448285819&u=37997"
```

### To parse the url variables use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($url, $fragments);
var_dump($fragments);//
/*
array(3) {
  ["token"]=>
  string(22) "U8h5Ma12SrlizPoFm-Nc5w"
  ["e"]=>
  string(10) "1448285819"
  ["u"]=>
  string(5) "37997"
}
*/
```